# Is the set of $k$-extendible states compact?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, mathematics, density-operator

Let  ∈ ℕ
. A state _ on a bipartite [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) A ⊗ B
is -extendible with respect to B if there exists a state _(_)
on A ⊗ B^(⊗), which is invariant under any permutation of the B
subsystems and such that _ =_ABi.

Is the set of $k$-extendible states compact?

N.B. bipartite means: "having or consisting of two parts."

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is:   = Tr__−1(_) ? Does k-1 mean $k^{-1}$ ?

Comment: What does "compact" mean here? Do you mean closed? Everything is bounded, it seems.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer Supposedly the trace over $k-1$ of the B systems.

Comment: it means trace out any (k-1) B subsystems.